# How can I connect my android phone to my PC via USB cable in MTP mode

Tags: usb-connection-mode, usb-drivers, mtp

I tried connecting my mobile **MOTO G** to my PC running Windows XP SP3.
I hear a sound notifying it is connected but in the *DEVICE MANAGER* all i get is a Unknown Device and under that there is XT 1033 with a question mark next to it.
The computer detects it when i connect it as PTP but not when connected as MTP. I don't know what the problem is. And the drivers don't get installed too.

Comment: Have you tried installing Microsoft's [Media Transfer Protocol Porting Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=19153)? MTP is not available on XP without this.

Comment: I did. But it didn't make any difference. @filoxo

Comment: Ok, then how about installing just the drivers (without the Motorola Device Manager)? This [XDA forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2550635) offers 32/64 bit USB/ADB drivers for the Moto G. You might need to clean out any previously installed software/drivers before you get the prompt for the device's drivers.

Comment: Nothing worked out in XP. So i just installed WIndows 7 and the drivers got installed automatically.